# Omit DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using XSLT 2.0 to transform the XML files to XHTML. I am using saxon9 processor for conversion. While converting, I am getting an error like

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\test\book.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified).

It’s looking for a DTD as the XML has the DOCTYPE declaration with PUBLIC id.

I was looking for the solution to resolve this error but I am not able to do that. I tried with resolver.jar.

I have downloaded resolver.jar and placed in the same location where the saxon.jar is located, and tried the following command line.

```
java -cp c:/saxon9/saxon9.jar;c:saxon9/resolver.jar; net.sf.saxon.Transform -x:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader -t -s:c:/test/sample2.xml -xsl:c:/test/body.xsl >c:/test/out /output.html
```

I am getting the same error message.

I referred few websites to use the resolver.jar but I am not clear with the instruction and not getting the desired output.

I found http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=XML_Catalogs.
Is this the correct solution to use resolver.jar to omit DOCTYPE declaration? If so kindly help on how to use this or is there any other method that can be used?

My XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE chapter PUBLIC "-//ES//DTD book DTD version 5.3.0//EN//XML" "book.dtd" [<!  ENTITY fx1 SYSTEM "fx1" NDATA IMAGE>]>
<chapter>
<info>
<ce:link locator="fx1"/>…
```

I have created the catalog.xml file as like below and stored in the same location.

```
<catalog prefer="public" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
<system systemId="-//ES//DTD book DTD version 5.3.0//EN//XML" uri="book.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

I have also defined the classpath in environmental variable as like:

```
c:\saxon9\saxon9.jar;c:\saxon\resolver.jarUsed the following command line for conversion(referred http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=XML_Catalogs)
```

But I am still facing the same problem and I can’t find where the exact problem is, and what else need to do?

```
C:\>java -cp c:\saxon9\saxon9.jar;c:\saxon9\resolver.jar -Dxml.catalog.files=c:\saxon9\catalog.xml net.sf.saxon.Transform -r:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver  -x:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader -y:org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader -xsl:c:\test\body1.xsl -s:c:\test\Main.xml -o:c:\test\output.html
```

but getting the following error

```
Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\test\book.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Timely help greatly appreciated as this is very urgent...

Comment: The public id ("-//ES//DTD book DTD version 5.3.0//EN//XML") is for a DTD published by [Elsevier](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/text_file/0018/111339/bk53_book530_dtd.txt).  It is not standalone, as it pulls in other declarations.  You aren't going to get far without the full distribution.  I would suggest removing the doctype declaration altogether and using non-validating parsers with Saxon.

Comment: Also, the entity declaration in the internal subset is broken: there should be no space between '<!' and 'ENTITY'.  Even with this fix, there is still the problem of no declaration for a notation named 'IMAGE'.

Comment: In the catalog that should be <public publicId="-//ES//DTD book DTD version 5.3.0//EN//XML" uri="book.dtd"> . But, again, your real problem is likely to be that you don't have the Elsevier DTDs at all.

Answer (score 2):

The xmllint tool worked for me.

```
xmllint --dropdtd -o file.xml file.xml
```

And as Thomas mentioned you can pipe the result to saxonb.

```
xmllint --dropdtd file.xml | saxonb-xslt -s:- -xsl:stylesheet.xsl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Linux system, you could strip the DOCTYPE declaration, e.g. using sed, and pipe the result into Saxon, like:

```
sed '/<!DOCTYPE/d' in.xml | saxonb-xslt -s:- -xsl:stylesheet.xsl
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am using Windows 7

Comment: sed is not a good idea in general as there is nothing requiring a doctype declaration to be entirely on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the form of the doctype declaration in your input XML file.  Since Saxon is looking for a 'C:\test\book.dtd', it sounds like that there is an external identifier present.  So you have something like one of these:

```
1. <!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "some-public-id" "c:\test\book.dtd">

2. <!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "c:\test\book.dtd">
```

The basic problem is that the system identifier portion ("c:\test\book.dtd") is a hard default.  It will always be looked for unless you use the catalogs mechanism to point elsewhere for the DTD.  (This is a flaw in the XML spec that we just have to live with.)

The first order of business is whether you have a DTD for your source XML format at all.  If you don't, and can't obtain one, then your only option is to pre-process the source XML and remove the entire external identifier portion (i.e. whichever of the two forms above that applies) of the doctype declaration.  Removing the entire doctype declaration is also okay as long as it does not have an internal subset (other declarations between a pair of '[' and ']' delimiters.)

If you do have the DTD, you could put a copy at c:\test\book.dtd.  If you don't want to do that, you will have to use the catalog mechanism to point Saxon (and its resolver) to the desired location.  It isn't enough to just put the resolver.jar in your classpath.  You also need to give it something to work with!

In particular, you need to give it a catalog file (via the xml.catalog.files environment variable - note the command line of the example in the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/saxon/index.php?title=XML_Catalogs)); and you need an entry in the catalog for the DTD of the input XML format. This should map the system identifier 'c:\test\book.dtd' (and/or the public identifier if the source XML has one in the doctype declaration) to the location in your filesystem where you've put the DTD.

Comment: I have edited my question with my XML and catalog file, and the command line which I used, but still I am getting the same error...

Comment: Do you have the DTD at all?  It is a file with contents that look like [this](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/text_file/0018/111339/bk53_book530_dtd.txt). If you don't, and can't get it, then you need to use a non-validating parser in the -x option.